# Droid browser causing havoc on my site

Tags: android, webkit

I have a mobile-optimized site that uses a pretty simple trick of serving a different page based on browser width. This worked great until the Droid came along, with its very high pixel density screen.

I understand that the default setting of the screen is 800 pixels wide (significantly wider than my width detect script, which is making its decision of which page to serve at 500 pixels). However, the Droid browser seems to arbitrarily decide to report a smaller width, and thusly serve the smaller-width page. But not in a predictable manor.

As a result, the experience for an end user is completely random: sometimes they see a wide page they have to zoom in on, sometimes they see a page that's scaled just right to their window.

I have written a small script that reports the screen width and, even when forcing the viewport to a specific pixel size, I have had some users still report an 800 pixel width (even in vert orientation) and others report the fixed width.

Is there a way of definitively setting the width for the Droid's browser? Is this a bug? Am I just simply not thinking something through? Frankly, it's starting to feel like designing in a dark cave with my hands tied behind my back.

Comment: Yes. Duh, sorry: http://www.cellstories.net
And the simple screen width script: http://www.sinkerdocs.com/wintest.html

Comment: I've visited your site on my Droid, and I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. The root page of the site tells me about cellstories, but doesn't display an actual story; it merely prompts me to visit the site "on a mobile device". However, I could get the story to display by clicking "about cellstories" and then "back" (the big button on the page, not the "back" button on my Droid). Is the Droid not reporting user-agent correctly, either ? In any case, the sizing seemed correct on the Droid, even though wintest.html reported seemingly random values.

Comment: Yep, that's *exactly* the problem. The back button sends you right back to the original entrance page--should have no different experience than when you first pulled up the site. But it's now serving the small-screen version. Obviously, you didn't do anything to your screen in the interim. Droid seems to decide seemingly at random what size its screen is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're determining whether to display the mobile page (the story) or the description page by screen width. From my understanding, it would probably be better to detect mobile phones by user agent or user a pre-built browser detection script to determine which page to display. I often use browser windows less than 800px wide, so an issue like this would have prevented me from seeing the page correctly on my browser.

Comment: Have any recommendations for a pre-built browser detection script?